# Is there a way to reconstruct a "full-life" from a "half-life" of a decomposing piece of waste?

Tags: experimental-physics, definition, half-life

*(please gently redirect me if it's a wrong SE and don't question-ban me, I mean no harm)*

> Paper products have a lag time of 1.5–2.0 years before methane production, **a ‘half-life’
> of 10–20 years**, [...]

*(from [here](https://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/pdf1997/mical97a.pdf), p. 150)*

Does it mean that it takes 20–40 years for a piece of paper or cardboard to fully decompose in a landfill? Apparently, not, the two halves are not identical. What is a "full-life" then? Can it be calculated with a "half-life" estimate at hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is asymptotic. Every 10-20 years you have half of what you had going into that time period. So in 20-40 years you get 1/4. Half of half.. In 30-60 years, you have 1/8th. Half of a half of a half. If 100% = full then mathematically it would take infinite time because you can never reach zero. You can certainly calculate how long it would take to reach a set percentage however so there is no such thing as a full-life.

The math is just like that for time constants except instead of e which gives you about 63% per iteration, you use 0.5 for half

$A = A_02^{-t/t_{1/2}}=A_0e^{-t/\tau}$

- $A$ final amount
- $A_0$ original amount
- $t$ time elapsed
- $\tau$ time constant (mean lifetime), $t_{1/2}$ half-life

Every $t$ that is a multiple of half-life $t_{1/2}$ multiplies another factor $1/2$ to the original value.

Comment: It's interesting because I would never imagine that paper can decompose infinitely. Suppose, the percentage is 99% (it's as good as 100%). What would it come to?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Well it's mathematically like that. In reality there are only finite number of molecules but there are a great number of them so you can keep subdividing very far so it would take a very long time until you get 4, then 2, then 1, then zero.

Comment: The behaviour of large numbers of particles is predictable (through statistical processes such as the central limit theorem). Conversely, the behaviour of one particle is totally random, so it's impossible to predict when that last particle will decay to zero.

Comment: @TobyMak Yes, half-life is statistical. 3.32 half-life time constants for 90% reduction.

Comment: For the mathematical details: [Central Limit Theorem for exponential distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019054/central-limit-theorem-for-exponential-distribution)

Comment: Could you provide me with your calculation? I don't think I understand your formula

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev You need logarithms to solve for the exponent. Set $A = 0.1A_o$ Solve for t in terms of $\tau$. Also no negative on the exponent. My error.

Comment: Thankfully, I have a cell phone that can do logarithms for me. Just show me how your formula works please

Comment: I already explained that in the last sentence of the post.

Comment: Well, I don't understand your explanation. You never explained what A or Ao is, for one thing. Is it a percentage of decomposing matter? Should my phone solve this then: 0,01=1*0,5^(t/10) (if we take the half-life of ten years)?

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean. See edits. It can be an absolute or percentage amount since they just cancel out to a fraction anyways when dividing by both sides.

Comment: So what and how should I type in? Guide me through please

Comment: What you wrote earlier is correct

Comment: Does it take 66 years (https://ibb.co/BykqVHY)? Are you kidding me? It's insane

Comment: Oh, yeah. I used 10% in my 3.32 half life calculation. Not 1% like you asked.  Yes 6.64 time constants for 1%

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev In terms of whether the decay lifetime is really infinite, that's discusssed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/676909).

Comment: @J.G. it's ridiculously complex for me, I don't understand it at all. And, by the way, the rate of biological decomposition is not constant with time, unlike nuclear decay, so maybe all of it doesn't apply here much

Comment: @DKNguyen Can you provide me with a paper that supports the notion that that nuclear decay formula applies to organic decomposition too? They work differently, and maybe you deconstruct "full-lives" for organic stuff differently too

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I don't know that in depth. What I described is just the generic equation and definition for half-life irrespective of the specific topic. I don't think organic decomposition is statistical though but the concept of time constants does not need to be statistical nor does it need to be 1/2. For example, RC time in electrical circuits are not statistical and follow 1/e, rather than 1/2.

Comment: Do you have anything to say about the way your formula was altered?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Not really. It's numerically the same.