# How accurate is radioactive decay rate formulae and is there room for error?

Tags: radioactivity

So, lets ay I have 4 different samples of 1 mole of a radioactive element, and i check them after time of 1 half life has passed

before checking them can I be absolutely sure that

1. all the 4 experiments will have exactly the same amount of atoms left?
2. they all will have exactly(to a single atom) 0.5 moles left?

(assuming the conditions are same for all the samples)

Comment: I suspect you can't measure those moles to better than 1 part per trillion.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/676893).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to both questions is no. The decay of an individual atom in a fixed time interval is probabilistic in nature, i.e. there is a probability (that depends on the length of the time interval) for deacy that is not equal to 0 or 1.

When large ensembles of atoms are together, one can use laws of probability do deduce how one *expects* the number of decays to change with time, but there is still room for randomness since the number of atoms is finite.

Comment: thanks so much dude, i was really could not find my question answered on any of the books i have...

Answer (score 13):

Actually your experiment is a prime example of the
[binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

> the binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$
> is the discrete probability distribution of the number
> of successes in a sequence of $n$ independent experiments,
> each asking a yes–no question, and each with its own
> Boolean-valued outcome: success (with probability $p$)
> or failure (with probability  $q=1-p$).

In your case you do the yes-no question "*Has the atom
decayed after one half-time?*" for each atom.
So $n=6.02\cdot 10^{23}$ is the initial number
of atoms, and $p=\frac{1}{2}$ is the probability that
an individual atom has decayed.

According to [*Binomial distribution - Expected value
and variance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Expected_value_and_variance) the mean value of decayed atoms is
$$\mu=np = 3.01\cdot 10^{23}=0.5\text{ mol}$$
and its [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) is
$$\sigma=\sqrt{np(1-p)}=3.88\cdot 10^{11}=6.4\cdot 10^{-13}\text{ mol}$$

In most cases ($\approx 68$%) the actual number of decayed atoms
will be in the range $\mu\pm\sigma$.
Of course this tiny relative deviation is far beyond measurable.

But for smaller numbers of decayed atoms (let us say with $\mu=100$)
it is easy to verify the predicted $\sigma$ in experiment.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question can be illustrated with a simple example.
Tossing a coin and comparing the number of heads with the total number of throws.
Just to give you an idea of the scale that you are asking consider starting with a given number of radioactive nuclei (number of coin tosses) with a probability of decay (a head) of $0.5$ in a given time (half-life) and in that time **exactly** one half of them decay (exactly half are heads).

This is an example of a binomial distribution with probability $=0.5$.
[A good calculator for the computations is provide by WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=binomial+probability+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22BinomialProbabilities%22%2C+%22x%22%7D+-%3E%221%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22BinomialProbabilities%22%2C+%22n%22%7D+-%3E%222%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22BinomialProbabilities%22%2C+%22p%22%7D+-%3E%221%2F2%22).

[image]

You will note that as the number of radioactive atoms (coin tosses) increases the probability of **exactly** half of the decaying (coin showing a head) decreases.
So for $0.5$ of a mole of radioactive atoms the probability of exactly half of them decaying will be rather small.

This is equivalent to there being **exactly** 0.25 mole of heads after 0.5 mole of tosses!

However the probability of this happening, although very small, is not as small as I expected, $\approx 10^{-12}$.
The value can be obtained by assuming that the binomial approximates to a normal distribution for large values of $n$, the number of atoms.
With a probability of $0.5$ the mean of the normal distribution is $3\times 10^{23}/2=1.5\times 10^{23}$ with a standard deviation of $\sqrt{3\times 10^{23}*0.5*0.5} \approx 2.74\times 10^{11}$.
With a deviation of 0.5 from the mean, $z=0.5/2.74\times 10^{11}= 1.83 \times 10^{-12}$, [leading to a probability of the order of one in a trillion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=normal+distribution+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22NormalProbabilities%22%2C+%22z%22%7D+-%3E%22-0.00000000000183%22).